# Oracle: How to get a list of CTXSYS.CONTEXT indices?

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

I can get a list of indices by querying USER_OBJECTS.

How can I distinguish which of these indices are of type CXTSYS.CONTEXT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`USER_INDEXES`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1109.htm#REFRN20088) (and `ALL_INDEXES`) contains this information:

```
select index_name, table_name, index_type
from user_indexes
where ityp_owner = 'CTXSYS'
  and ityp_name = 'CONTEXT'
```